# How to read over 1M records from CSV?

Tags: r, csv

My CSV file has around 2M (million) records. If I open it with excel, I can only view around 1M of it (I believe excel places a cap on it). When I try to view the csv within RStudio, it doesn't let me see all 2M records. It only shows me the same amount of records excel does. **How can I view all 2M of the records in RStudio?**

I'm using the code below to read the file if you're curious. I can view the exact same amount of records in excel as I do in R. But I know there's way more records.

```
df <- read.csv("bigfile.csv", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: How many columns? 2M records is not that much nowadays...

Comment: @RuiBarradas there's 16 columns

Comment: I'll try to give an answer: The way you look at not small datasets (and 2M rows is far off from *big*data)  in R is by using code - You use code to check for missing or inconsistent values, use code to find patterns and use code to manipulate it. While 2M is not bigdata, it is to much to check visually anyways.... at least thats my take on it

Comment: @dario Thanks. I am aware this is far from bigdata but I assume someone with bigdata experience would know how to help me out, hence the tag. I am using code to format the data from long to wide. I like to scroll down in the pane in RStudio to make sure everything looks right but I am worried that RStudio isn't formatting all 2M rows and just 1M rows that I can see.

Comment: 1) `header = TRUE` already is the default of `read.csv`, it doesn't hurt but it does nothing; 2) After reading, what is the output of `dim(df)`? 3) To see the data `str(df) or `summary(df)` are better than to print a large data set.

Comment: Then check that using code `nrow(dataset)` etc...

Comment: I removed the rstudio and excel tags because they're not actually relevant. You can `View()` outside of RStudio just as well as with it. Otherwise, what are you looking to achieve by viewing that many rows? You certainly won't be able to make sense of it without doing some form of aggregation, so you shouldn't need to do much outside of making sure the data is properly formatted.

Comment: The problem is that (as @dario says) it's just not practical to examine **two million rows** visually to see if there's something funny going on. If you can visually examine 100 rows/second, it will take you 5+ hours to look at the whole data set; if 1000 rows/second, it's still about 30 minutes (and you'll probably miss something). You could examine a random subsample ...

Answer (score 1):

I use a free app called Large Text File Viewer (LTFViewer) to quickly review large files.  It has a search tool and a goto_line tool, very handy for investigating issues.

Once you have done the import to R, you can do:

```
str(df)
head(df)
names(df)
```

You can also try

```
View(df)
```

But that works less well as your file size increases, as you have noticed.